# XmlMapper missing root while parsing to LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, xml, jackson, linkedhashmap, xmlmapper

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
    LinkedHashMap result = xmlMapper.readValue("<root><a>1</a><b>2</b></root>", LinkedHashMap.class);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

It returns:

```
{a=1, b=2}
```

How can I make it keep root element like this:

```
{
   root = { 
      a = 1, 
      b = 2
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please consider creating a real POJO for this use-case as maps are [not supported for root elements](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/issues/237#issuecomment-303190666).

Comment: Pojo will help only if I know root name upfront, won't it?

Comment: Yes this would be the simplest way but I am yet also looking for a configurable way.
It has to be somethhing like ```xmlMapper.readerFor(XmlBean.class).withRootName("root").readValue("<root><a>1</a><b>2</b></root>");```